# create clickable or markable svg objects

Tags: javascript, svg

I have this SVG below for a car layout, how can I make it as clickable separated objects [just like how did this guy make wit the map](https://www.jonathan-petitcolas.com/2013/07/18/create-clickable-svg-france-regions-map.html)?

https://svgshare.com/i/6BM.svg

My aim is to make the user able to mark the damaged parts of the car with mouse click, but i couldn't know how the best way to achieve that.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using classes on every path to detect the hover effect, and simple jQuery click listeners.

[image]